# Laravel 4.2 | Manually auth user

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I've got in my control panel an option to log manually an user:

```
Auth::logout();

\Session::flush();
\Session::regenerate();

// login as request user
Auth::login($user);
```

Well, at my home localhost it works pretty well. But, when I try it on the web server, something strange happened - it seems that the login has succeeded (I can see the user details on the page; name, email, image and etc.), but when I moved to another page, it just dropping me away to login page.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you check the route setting? ref: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes

Comment: Yes, sometimes it works but mostly not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the first line:

```
Auth::logout();
```

Probably the function callback dropping me away every time.
Remove this line and it just works well.